# UIApplication Idle Timer

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

This is a simple question and I can not seem to find any information on it, but I just want to know if the following code will get my app rejected or not. Basically, is this a private API

```
[application setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

I want to add this to my AppDelegate under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. I just do not want to use something so simple and get my app rejected. Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's public, though apple advises:

> Important You should set this property only if necessary and should be
>   sure to reset it to NO when the need no longer exists. Most
>   applications should let the system turn off the screen when the idle
>   timer elapses. This includes audio applications. With appropriate use
>   of Audio Session Services, playback and recording proceed
>   uninterrupted when the screen turns off. The only applications that
>   should disable the idle timer are mapping applications, games, or
>   similar programs with sporadic user interaction.

So you should be okay if your app is as they describe, or if you use it sparingly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I will try to build my application so I do not have to use it, but if the need comes up I may have to resort to it. Thanks again!

Comment: I just got an app rejected for using this, and the Apple reviewer said it was an undocumented API, however it clearly is documented! :( Not sure if we're really allowed to use it or not.